# Vavr source jar is missing classes

Tags: eclipse, maven, java-8, open-source, vavr

When trying to look up the implementation of certain classes in [Vavr](http://www.vavr.io), such as `Patterns.java`, for example, with all its inner classes, i.e. `Patterns.$Success`, Eclipse is refusing to open them because they are not contained in the source jar **(vavr-0.9.2-sources.jar)** downloaded from Maven central.

[image]

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
    <artifactId>vavr</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
    <artifactId>vavr-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Where can I get a jar with full sources?

Comment: Another nice catch, thanks for pointing out. Issue created: [vavr#2209](https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr/issues/2209)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, that class is generated by the `vavr-match` annotation processor module, and its output is not added to the resulting source artifact, which is an omission in my opinion, so I'll file an issue about it to see whether we could include it from now on. The source class that triggers the annotation processor is `io.vavr.$` (note that Eclipse has trouble opening that class via its *Open Type* dialog, but you can try searching for `io.vavr.` <- note the space at the end).

I'll include a version of that generated `Patterns.java` source file in my answer below, and hope that the next release of vavr will have that file included in its source artifact.

```java
// @formatter:off
// CHECKSTYLE:OFF
package io.vavr;

import io.vavr.API.Match.Pattern;
import io.vavr.API.Match.Pattern0;
import io.vavr.API.Match.Pattern1;
import io.vavr.API.Match.Pattern2;
import io.vavr.API.Match.Pattern3;
import io.vavr.API.Match.Pattern4;
import io.vavr.API.Match.Pattern5;
import io.vavr.API.Match.Pattern6;
import io.vavr.API.Match.Pattern7;
import io.vavr.API.Match.Pattern8;
import io.vavr.collection.List;
import io.vavr.concurrent.Future;
import io.vavr.control.Either;
import io.vavr.control.Option;
import io.vavr.control.Try;
import io.vavr.control.Validation;

// GENERATED BY VAVR <<>> derived from io.vavr.$

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public final class Patterns {

    private Patterns() {
    }

    public static final Pattern0<Tuple0> $Tuple0 = Pattern0.of(Tuple0.class);

    public static <T1, _1 extends T1> Pattern1<Tuple1<T1>, _1> $Tuple1(Pattern<_1, ?> p1) {
        return Pattern1.of(Tuple1.class, p1, io.vavr.$::Tuple1);
    }

    public static <T1, T2, _1 extends T1, _2 extends T2> Pattern2<Tuple2<T1, T2>, _1, _2> $Tuple2(Pattern<_1, ?> p1, Pattern<_2, ?> p2) {
        return Pattern2.of(Tuple2.class, p1, p2, io.vavr.$::Tuple2);
    }

    public static <T1, T2, T3, _1 extends T1, _2 extends T2, _3 extends T3> Pattern3<Tuple3<T1, T2, T3>, _1, _2, _3> $Tuple3(Pattern<_1, ?> p1, Pattern<_2, ?> p2, Pattern<_3, ?> p3) {
        return Pattern3.of(Tuple3.class, p1, p2, p3, io.vavr.$::Tuple3);
    }

    public static <T1, T2, T3, T4, _1 extends T1, _2 extends T2, _3 extends T3, _4 extends T4> Pattern4<Tuple4<T1, T2, T3, T4>, _1, _2, _3, _4> $Tuple4(Pattern<_1, ?> p1, Pattern<_2, ?> p2, Pattern<_3, ?> p3, Pattern<_4, ?> p4) {
        return Pattern4.of(Tuple4.class, p1, p2, p3, p4, io.vavr.$::Tuple4);
    }

    public static <T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, _1 extends T1, _2 extends T2, _3 extends T3, _4 extends T4, _5 extends T5> Pattern5<Tuple5<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5> $Tuple5(Pattern<_1, ?> p1, Pattern<_2, ?> p2, Pattern<_3, ?> p3, Pattern<_4, ?> p4, Pattern<_5, ?> p5) {
        return Pattern5.of(Tuple5.class, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, io.vavr.$::Tuple5);
    }

    public static <T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, _1 extends T1, _2 extends T2, _3 extends T3, _4 extends T4, _5 extends T5, _6 extends T6> Pattern6<Tuple6<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6> $Tuple6(Pattern<_1, ?> p1, Pattern<_2, ?> p2, Pattern<_3, ?> p3, Pattern<_4, ?> p4, Pattern<_5, ?> p5, Pattern<_6, ?> p6) {
        return Pattern6.of(Tuple6.class, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, io.vavr.$::Tuple6);
    }

    public static <T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, _1 extends T1, _2 extends T2, _3 extends T3, _4 extends T4, _5 extends T5, _6 extends T6, _7 extends T7> Pattern7<Tuple7<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7> $Tuple7(Pattern<_1, ?> p1, Pattern<_2, ?> p2, Pattern<_3, ?> p3, Pattern<_4, ?> p4, Pattern<_5, ?> p5, Pattern<_6, ?> p6, Pattern<_7, ?> p7) {
        return Pattern7.of(Tuple7.class, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, io.vavr.$::Tuple7);
    }

    public static <T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, _1 extends T1, _2 extends T2, _3 extends T3, _4 extends T4, _5 extends T5, _6 extends T6, _7 extends T7, _8 extends T8> Pattern8<Tuple8<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8> $Tuple8(Pattern<_1, ?> p1, Pattern<_2, ?> p2, Pattern<_3, ?> p3, Pattern<_4, ?> p4, Pattern<_5, ?> p5, Pattern<_6, ?> p6, Pattern<_7, ?> p7, Pattern<_8, ?> p8) {
        return Pattern8.of(Tuple8.class, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, io.vavr.$::Tuple8);
    }

    public static <T, _1 extends T, _2 extends List<T>> Pattern2<List.Cons<T>, _1, _2> $Cons(Pattern<_1, ?> p1, Pattern<_2, ?> p2) {
        return Pattern2.of(List.Cons.class, p1, p2, io.vavr.$::Cons);
    }

    public static <T> Pattern0<List.Nil<T>> $Nil() {
        return Pattern0.of(List.Nil.class);
    }

    public static <T, _1 extends Option<Try<T>>> Pattern1<Future<T>, _1> $Future(Pattern<_1, ?> p1) {
        return Pattern1.of(Future.class, p1, io.vavr.$::Future);
    }

    public static <L, R, _1 extends R> Pattern1<Either.Right<L, R>, _1> $Right(Pattern<_1, ?> p1) {
        return Pattern1.of(Either.Right.class, p1, io.vavr.$::Right);
    }

    public static <L, R, _1 extends L> Pattern1<Either.Left<L, R>, _1> $Left(Pattern<_1, ?> p1) {
        return Pattern1.of(Either.Left.class, p1, io.vavr.$::Left);
    }

    public static <T, _1 extends T> Pattern1<Option.Some<T>, _1> $Some(Pattern<_1, ?> p1) {
        return Pattern1.of(Option.Some.class, p1, io.vavr.$::Some);
    }

    public static <T> Pattern0<Option.None<T>> $None() {
        return Pattern0.of(Option.None.class);
    }

    public static <T, _1 extends T> Pattern1<Try.Success<T>, _1> $Success(Pattern<_1, ?> p1) {
        return Pattern1.of(Try.Success.class, p1, io.vavr.$::Success);
    }

    public static <T, _1 extends Throwable> Pattern1<Try.Failure<T>, _1> $Failure(Pattern<_1, ?> p1) {
        return Pattern1.of(Try.Failure.class, p1, io.vavr.$::Failure);
    }

    public static <E, T, _1 extends T> Pattern1<Validation.Valid<E, T>, _1> $Valid(Pattern<_1, ?> p1) {
        return Pattern1.of(Validation.Valid.class, p1, io.vavr.$::Valid);
    }

    public static <E, T, _1 extends E> Pattern1<Validation.Invalid<E, T>, _1> $Invalid(Pattern<_1, ?> p1) {
        return Pattern1.of(Validation.Invalid.class, p1, io.vavr.$::Invalid);
    }

}
// CHECKSTYLE:ON
// @formatter:on
```

Edit: [issue opened: vavr#2209](https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr/issues/2209)